# Jupyter does not run with sagemath installed

Tags: macos, jupyter, sage

I am running on a mac, with sagemath installed and Anaconda also.
Sage is working fine, though Jupyter notebook doesn't run.

I get the following error:

```
Rois-MBP:~ roi$ /anaconda/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
[W 22:32:09.192 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 595, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1069, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 837, in init_configurables
    parent=self,
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py", line 19, in __init__
    specs = self.find_kernel_specs() or {}
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py", line 129, in find_kernel_specs
    self.conda_info = self._conda_info()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py", line 29, in _conda_info
    p = subprocess.check_output(["conda", "info", "--json"]
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conda'
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Other apps like spyder do run successfully.
Can I solve it somehow?

Comment: I had a similar problem, except for me the sage didn't work with a similar error. This might help: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2016-February/468495.html

Comment: Thanks, @Keivan but the `.bashrc` file seems fine. I found another way to do it, and I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to run jupyter notebook through sage:

Just run from the terminal: `./sage -n jupyter`