# Running python on Sage keeps getting stuck - not showing image

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to run sage in python mode. (The reason I don't run Jupyter is that it doesn't run on my machine - I don't know why. [see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409330/jupyter-does-not-run-with-sagemath-installed)).
But it keeps getting stuck all the time. 
For example, I try to run this code:

```
img_1=np.random.poisson(lam=300,size=(1024,1024))
img_1=img_1-img_1.mean()
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.imshow(img_1)
plt.title("wowo")
plt.show()
```

But the image is not showing.

Comment: I think we need a little more information here.  Exactly where are you running Sage in python mode?  Is this the Sage notebook?  In that case `plt.show()` does indeed not always immediately show things, because it's generating something in matplotlib in a temporary directory.  See https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8526/is-there-a-simple-way-to-plot-an-image-in-a-notebook-ie-the-output-of-the-imshow-function-in-matplotlib/ for something probably helpful.

Comment: On a separate note, if Jupyter doesn't run that is a bug; again, we'd need specific details.

Comment: @kcrisman I'm running Sage in python mode because I couldn't get Sage to plot what I wanted. So I thought that in python mode it'll work. And I edited the question with the link to the question I posted about it yesterday.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were that questioner.  I don't know enough about Anaconda to answer that, but I do know that it often causes conflicts.  However, you should be able to run Sage (and lots of other things) with the Jupyter notebook in Sage itself, via `sage -n jupyter`.  You can switch the kernel to Sage or Python inside that.

Comment: I now run jupyter through sage, but now I have the same problem the image is not showing. When I run the notebook on the sage cloud it works fine. I tried to add also `plt.savefig('')` but it didn't help. Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: I can't answer in terms of Jupyter, because I don't use it.  I assume that whatever works in an ordinary Jupyter notebook would work there too, but I can't verify that.

Comment: Thanks. Found that adding `%matplotlib inline` solved it in Jupyter, while in sage it screwed up thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
plt.savefig('')
```

and it should show fine.  Sage notebook needs the figure to be saved in a local directory for the cell, and this is one way to accomplish that.